# How to monitor and diagnose Wi-Fi problems

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, diagnostic

I have a home Wi-Fi network used by few laptops and mobile devices. 
From time to time I get complaints from my family that the network feels slow lately. I restart the access point and the complaints cease for some time but not permanently.

Now what steps can I take to

- Monitor network quality so I can react before problems escalate so somebody feels the need to complain?
- Diagnose the root cause of the problem instead of dumb restart and hoping it will help?

I'm willing invest a little in diagnostics / resolution if needed.

I have some devices that run around the clock (now on wire but I can enable wireless radio on them) to run some continuous monitoring.

Comment: There are smartphone apps that help you determine if you have a lot of interference on a given frequency channel.  That is a great start.  Specific suggestion, lists of possible solutions, are all no on topic though so I can't supply them.  If there are lots of access points on the same frequency and near the same channel, the slower your connection to your own access point, the only solution is to isolate yourself from those other access points as much as you can